# How to validate time slot conflicts in my sessions?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, mongoose

I have a Session model, which has a date, a start time, and an end time, as shown below
// Assuming the Session model is define in this same file
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

```
const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: [true, 'Date is required for session']
    },

    start: {
        type: Date,
        required: [true, 'Please specify end time for session']
    },

    end: {
      type: Date,
      required: [true, 'Please specify end time for session']
    },

    owner: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

    participants: {
      type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
      ref: 'User'
    },
 })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Session', SessionSchema)
```

In my "/session-create" route, I want to ensure before creating the session, that the owner does not have another conflicting section in the session time interval. Meaning the time interval of the new session should be outside of the time interval of any other existing sessions of the owner.

How do I do this ? I am confused about how I should go into ensuring there are no conflicting sessions within their time intervals.

Here is my session-create route:

```
post("/create-session", (req, res) => {
     const { date, start, end } = req.body
     
     // Getting the start datetime
     startHours = start.slice(0, 2)
     startMinutes = start.slice(3)
     startDateTime = new Date(date).setHours(startHours, startMinutes)

     // Getting the end datetime
     endHours = end.slice(0, 2)
     endMinutes = end.slice(3)
     endDateTime = new Date(date).setHours(endHours, endMinutes)
     
     // Session owner cannot have 2 time-conflicting sessions
     // Session start time should not in be in the 
         // time interval of already existing sessions, i.e,

     // Session end time should not be within the time interval of already 
         // existing sessions
}
```

How do I make sure that the session owner cannot have 2 time-conflicting sessions during session creation ? In other words, how do I validate at the time of creation that a session start time is not in the
time interval of already existing sessions and that a session end time is not within the time intrerval of an already existing session ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query if a session with a start date less than body.date and end date greater than body.date, and if one exists return error

```
post("/create-session", (req, res) => {
  const { date, start, end } = req.body

  // Getting the start datetime
  startHours = start.slice(0, 2)
  startMinutes = start.slice(3)
  startDateTime = new Date(date).setHours(startHours, startMinutes)

  // Getting the end datetime
  endHours = end.slice(0, 2)
  endMinutes = end.slice(3)
  endDateTime = new Date(date).setHours(endHours, endMinutes)
  
  const existingSession = await findOne({ $and: [{ startDate: { $lt: startDateTime } }, { endDate: { $gt: startDateTime } }] })
  if (existingSession) return res.status(400).send({err: "not allowed"})

  // Session owner cannot have 2 time-conflicting sessions
  // Session start time should not in be in the 
      // time interval of already existing sessions, i.e,

  // Session end time should not be within the time interval of already 
      // existing sessions
})
```

Comment: Great but your answer only takes into account 1 case. What if  the existing session starts later than the current session but ends within the current session time interval.

Comment: Also the sessions must be owned by the same user

Comment: You can add the same validation for the end time date using $or and regarding the owner you should be able to check using req.user